# ServerSocket.accept() throwing SocketTimeoutException with null message

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket, socket-timeout-exception

I am trying to get an instance of Socket from ServerSocket Object. But, it always prints

```
SocketTimeoutException = null
```

There is my code:

```
try {
    // We listen for new connections
    Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> In TRY ");
    try {
        servSock = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> In TRY # IO Exception = " +e.getMessage());
        servSock = new ServerSocket();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> In TRY # E xception = " +e.getMessage());
    }

    // DNS Emitter (Bonjour)
    byte[] hwAddr = getHardwareAdress();
    emitter = new BonjourEmitter(name, getStringHardwareAdress(hwAddr), port);

    //Setting Timeout
    servSock.setSoTimeout(10000);


    Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> stopThread = " +stopThread);

    while (!stopThread) {
        try {
            //********** This is throwing Exception ***************//
            Socket socket = servSock.accept();
            servSock.setReuseAddress(true);
            Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> got connection from " + socket.toString());

            new RTSPResponder(hwAddr, socket).start();

        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> SocketTimeoutException = " + e.getMessage());
           //********* here I am getting exception **************//         

        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> Exception = " + e.getMessage());
            servSock.close();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {

    Log.d("ShairPort", "Service >> TRY # CATCH IOException = " + e.getMessage());
    throw new RuntimeException(e);

}
```

**Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong, so that I can resolve this issue.**

```
02-06 18:14:08.300: W/System.err(2245): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
02-06 18:14:08.300: W/System.err(2245):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
02-06 18:14:08.300: W/System.err(2245):     at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:203)
02-06 18:14:08.310: W/System.err(2245):     at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:128)
02-06 18:14:08.310: W/System.err(2245):     at vavi.apps.shairport.LaunchThread.run(LaunchThread.java:99)
02-06 18:14:08.310: W/System.err(2245): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
02-06 18:14:08.320: W/System.err(2245):     at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
02-06 18:14:08.320: W/System.err(2245):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
02-06 18:14:08.320: W/System.err(2245):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
02-06 18:14:08.320: W/System.err(2245):     ... 3 more
```

Comment: at which line you're getting NPE ?

Comment: I am not getting NPE.. Its SocketTimeoutException with getMessage() as NULL, in catch(SocketTimeoutException e)

Comment: Are you getting it 10 seconds after you start the `ServerSocket`?

Comment: yes, its more than that.. its approx 20 secs.

Comment: It doesn't 'throw ' `SocketTimeoutException = null`. It *prints* that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting a ten second timeout on the server socket.

The `accept()` method will therefore throw a `SocketTimeoutException` if no connection arrives within ten seconds.

If you don't want that behaviour, don't set the timeout, or raise it.

I have no idea why you're surprised at getting a timeout when you're setting it yourself.

NB It is utterly pointless to call `setReuseAddress()` on the server socket after it is bound, let alone every time you accept a new connection.

Comment: You set a ten minute timeout and you got a timeout after ten minutes. Why are you surprised? This is not making any sense.